# Screen moves after CCTextField editing start

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d 3.0 RC4.
When `textField` in `CCTextField` receive `becomeFirstResponder` screen moves down even though there is no need for it. I think this animation purpose is to show the text field if it's covered by keyboard. But I get this animation event if text field is on top and there is plenty of space for keyboard.
Is it possible to disable such animation?

Comment: This has still not been fixed... As it stands, CCTextField is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Macgeo's suggestion I made the following edit to the CCTextField class:

Add a property in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL movesViewOnFocus;
```

Then edit the implementation like so:

```
- (void) focusOnTextField
{
    if (!self.movesViewOnFocus) {
        return;
    }
```

And:

```
- (void) endFocusingOnTextField
{
    if (!self.movesViewOnFocus) {
        return;
    }
```

This is a 30 second hack and I have not tested it more than one or two times. But by default it would disable the move on focus. Of course it wouldn't work when turning it on if the textfield is already selected etc but at least it's a start. I'll suggest it to the Cocos2D devs.

Comment: If you do use this code, make sure to explicitly set movesViewOnFocus to NO in your app code and add a link to this article in a comment. When cocos2d updates in the future there is no guarantee that this fix has made it in there, and at least I hate tracking down lost fixes like this one.

Answer (score 1):

CCTextfield moves CCDirector's opengl view to do this via the focusOnTextField method. It then moves it back with endFocusingOnTextField.

So if you wanted to disable it that's where I would start. I suppose you could adjust how it calculates the offset as well.